# Post to facebook page as user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Am working on facebook graph API for posting on facebook page.I have a webpage where each users can login and share contents on a facebook page.Consider certain organizations,each organization has there own facebook page.From my website any user having facebook account can come and share their feedbacks about that organization and that feedback should be posted in the facebook page of the particular organization.

I need to implement this using facebook javascript api,but am getting an error

```
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200
```

Here is my code:

```
FB.api('/page_id/feed', 'post', 
          { 
              message     : "It's awesome ...",
              name        : 'Feedback',
              to: '',
              from: '',
              description : 'Your description'
      }, 
      function(response) {

          if (!response || response.error) {
              //alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response.error));
          } else {
              alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
          }
      });
```

}

Please help

Thanks

Comment: why do you have `page_id` in from?? u said `users` would be sharing their feedbacks.

Comment: @ThePCWizard, he wants to post to a Facebook page …

Comment: Did you acquire adequate permissions first?

Comment: @ ThePCWizard Oh sorry..It is my fault..Please leave that..How can i do this thing?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/

Comment: @CBore How can i acquire permissions.Will you please tell me what are the permissions needed here for my requirements?

Comment: @user1018060 are u posting on a page that's owned by you? i mean are u the admin of that page on which u tried to post?

Comment: No itz not like that.The page is owned by someone else.The guy gonna post the feedback is an independent user..

Comment: @ ThePCWizard Okay thanks, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function login() {       
      FB.login(function (response) {              
          if (response.authResponse) {
              // connected  
              postFeedBack();
          } else {
              // cancelled
          }
      }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
  }

  function postFeedBack() {
        FB.api('/page_id/feed', 'post', {
            message: "My Feedback"
        }, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can u debug the function and tell what the response say..or do it like this: `alert(response.error);`

Comment: Am getting the same error in my console "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: I have tried console.log(response)..i got the same error message

Comment: error: Object
code: 200
message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
type: "OAuthException"

Comment: @user1018060 sorry, don't know why it's happening. are u using exact that I posted. Have you configured your site in app settings.

Comment: @ ThePCWizard Am using the exact code you have posted.In my site configuration settings i have given the site url. Is that enough?Should i need to take any permissions or something?Currently am not having any permissions.But in the code you have posted you have given "publish stream" as scope.Actually do we need to do something in facebook settings for acquiring this permission?

Comment: @user1018060 no, we don't need to do anything extra. I would suggest you to try it with some other user or even better use a Test User